# Problems running PHP script using Task Scheduler (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: php, azure, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2, azure-virtual-machine

I am using a Virtual Machine on Windows Azure. It is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter Service Pack 1.

I have a PHP script that does some routine work which includes connecting online and saving a few images from my website.

I have created a batch file called `myScript.bat` as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder\m.php"
```

Pretty simple. It works great when I double click and run the `.bat` file. The PHP script does it's job.

Now, the problem arises when I try to schedule the task using Task Scheduler.

In `General` I have selected: **Run only when the user is logged on** and **Run with highest privileges**

In the `Trigger` tab, I have set the trigger, say, for every hour.

And in `Actions` tab I have added the following:

**Start a program - C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder\myScript.bat**

---

Now. when I **Run** this task, I get a bunch of error messages like this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://...): failed to open stream: ...
Warning: copy(images/image11942.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyFolder\m.php

etc.
```

I have tried enabling all permissions for `MyFolder` and its subfolders, but still no help.

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: If you can host this php file on IIS, you can use http://ATrigger.com for simple scheduling without Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue running a script as a Scheduled Tasks from the Desktop.
When I moved it to a folder on the C: drive, I had no further problems.

Hope this helps....